# Strange ExecutionException when doing POST with JSON

Tags: java, playframework

I have this method:

```
/**
 * POST
 */
public static void create(String body) {
    Logger.info("APPOINTMENT create - json string: %s", body);

    Appointment appointment = null;
    try {
        appointment = new Gson().fromJson(body, Appointment.class);

        //services are detached, re-take them from db
        List<Service> refreshedServices = new ArrayList<Service>();
        for (final Service ser : appointment.services) {
            Service service = Service.findById(ser.id);
            refreshedServices.add(service);
        }
        appointment.services = refreshedServices;
        appointment.save();
        appointment.refresh();
        Logger.info("services refreshed");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger
                .info(
                        "An error has occured when trying to create an APPOINTMENT %s",
                        ex);
        response.status = Http.StatusCode.INTERNAL_ERROR;
        renderJSON(new StatusMessage(
                "An internal error has occured. Please try again later."));
    }

    renderJSON(appointment);
}
```

I'm testing it like this:

```
public void createAppointment(final Contact contact, final List<Service> services) throws Exception {
        Appointment app = new Appointment();
        app.userUid = "cristi-uid";
        app.name = "app1";
        app.contact = contact;

        String serviceAsJson = "{\"userUid\":\"cristi-uid\",\"name\":\"app1\",\"allDay\":false,\"contact\":{\"id\":"+contact.id+"},\"services\":[{\"id\":\""+services.get(0).getId()+"\"},{\"id\":\""+services.get(1).getId()+"\"}]}";
        Response response = POST("/appointment/create", "application/json", serviceAsJson);

        Logger.info("POST was done");
        Appointment appReturned = new Gson().fromJson(response.out.toString(), Appointment.class);

        Logger.info("appointment create response: %s", response.out.toString());

        assertIsOk(response);
        assertEquals(appReturned.name, app.name);
    }
```

Well, the issue is that it is throwing this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
at play.test.FunctionalTest.makeRequest(FunctionalTest.java:304)
at play.test.FunctionalTest.makeRequest(FunctionalTest.java:310)
at play.test.FunctionalTest.POST(FunctionalTest.java:152)
at play.test.FunctionalTest.POST(FunctionalTest.java:120)
at play.test.FunctionalTest.POST(FunctionalTest.java:116)
at AppointmentsTest.createAppointment(AppointmentsTest.java:61)
```

and I am unable to find out why.

It prints out `Logger.info("services refreshed");` after that it is throwing the exception...

Do you guys see anything wrong with this test POST?

**UPDATE**: Seems that the issues comes from trying to render the `appointment` as JSON:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.(LinkedHashMap.java:345)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.(LinkedHashMap.java:345)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$ValueIterator.(LinkedHashMap.java:387)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$ValueIterator.(LinkedHashMap.java:387)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.newValueIterator(LinkedHashMap.java:397)
at java.util.HashMap$Values.iterator(HashMap.java:910)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:192)
at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:879)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
```

Comment: I have no experience in Play framework, but I hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510762/proper-way-of-writing-functionaltest-in-playframework will help you.

Comment: Thanks but it did not help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the issues by going down and studying the error trace. Basically my `Appointment` object has some `ManyToMany` relations and it seems that renderJSON was giving `StackOverFlow` when trying to render those relations.

I've created another `Appointment` object and copy into it only the fields I need to be exported.

```
    Appointment appointmentOutput = new Appointment();
    appointmentOutput.id = appointment.id;
    appointmentOutput.name = appointment.name;

    renderJSON(appointmentOutput);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because:

> The Play framework comes bundled with Google’s JSON library Gson, but
>   the developers of this library have made some design choices that keep
>   it from being ideal for generating JSON that is going to be sent to
>   the HTTP client.

Erik Bakker [recommended](http://www.lunatech-research.fr/archives/2011/04/20/play-framework-better-json-serialization-flexjson) to use [FlexSon](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)